Underdetermined Conditions for QR Factorization
In my textbook, the following is a theorem:

Based on this theorem, the QR factorization for a given matrix A is flexible because we can choose any orthonormal basis and represent it as Q and get a corresponding upper-triangular square R. However, I ran into an issue in the following example.
Suppose A = $
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -3 \\
5 & 7 \\
2 & -2 \\
-4 & -6
\end{pmatrix}
$ and Q = $
\begin{pmatrix}
2/7 & -5/7 \\
5/7 & 2/7 \\
2/7 & -4/7 \\
-4/7 & -2/7
\end{pmatrix}
$
The Q was simply computed using the G-S algorithm and normalizing the basis vectors afterward. If we solve for R using the fact that $Q^TA = R$, we get R = $
\begin{pmatrix}
7 & 7 \\
0 & 7 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$, which is certainly upper-triangular. However, suppose we instead choose Q = $
\begin{pmatrix}
-5/7 & 2/7 \\
2/7 & 5/7 \\
-4/7 & 2/7 \\
-2/7 & -4/7
\end{pmatrix}
$, which is the same as the original Q, just with its columns interchanged. Thus, if the original Q is an orthonormal basis for the column space of A, then the new Q is certainly an orthonormal basis for the column space of A. Based on the theorem above, then, I should expect the resulting R to be upper-triangular. If we solve for R using the fact that $Q^TA = R$, we get R = $
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 7 \\
7 & 7 \\
\end{pmatrix} $, which is certainly not upper triangular. Barring a basic computational mistake, how can the above theorem be correct? There appear to be additional, unstated conditions for ensuring R is upper-triangular.
EDIT: Am I misinterpreting the above theorem? Is it instead an existence statement as opposed to a universal statement? That is, there exists a Q such that the following holds, NOT for all Q the following holds.

I think the requirement is that the first $k$ columns of $Q$ should form a basis for the span of the first $k$ columns of $A$ (for all $k$). But this is off the top of my head, so take it with a big grain a salt

And yes, the theorem as stated only claims that such a decomposition exists, not that any $Q$ will work.

If you do the matrix multiplication of any $m \times n$ $Q$ by an $n \times n$ upper triangular $R$, you can notice that the first column of the result is the first column of $Q$ scaled by $r_{1,1}$. This forces the values of the first column of $Q$ and $r_{1,1}$ to be what Gramm-Schmidt chooses them to be, or their negation. Going further, you can notice that all the elements in the $QR$ decomposition are, up to sign, forced to be what they are. The sign change in the columns of $Q$ corresponds to the sign change in the rows of $R$, so you've got a really limited choice in how to do the factoring.
